# "Tell apart" with "Could"

Tags: expressions

I'm familiar with phrase *"Tell somebody apart"* used with *"could"* in negative, i.e. :

> They were so different that I couldn't tell them apart.

My questions are:

1. Can *"Tell apart"* be used with objects? E.g. :

   > I couldn't tell these keys apart
2. Can *"Tell apart"* be used with *"could"* in positive? E.g. :

   > I can easily tell them apart

---

My student gave me this sentence:

> I’ve duck-taped my toothbrush, so we could tell apart which is whose.

Do you think it sounds correct?

Comment: The answer is yes

Comment: You don't need _apart_ in the last example. He's duct-taped his toothbrush so they can (_note:_ not ‘could’) tell which is his; or: so that they can tell the toothbrushes apart, he's duct-taped his own.

Comment: Saying 'They are so different that you couldn't tell them apart' sounds nonsense to me. I think you may mean 'They are so much alike that you couldn't tell them apart'.

Comment: yeah, I meant "They are so much alike" , I made a mistake there.

Answer (score 1):

The final example sentence sounds wrong to me. I suppose this is the case because "tell apart" is a phrasal verb that requires an object pronoun.

He duct-taped his toothbrush so he could tell **it** apart from the other toothbrushes.

If he hadn´t, it would be impossible to tell **them** apart.

And, as someone answered in a comment, the answer to your other questions is yes.

Comment: It doesn't require an object pronoun, but it does require a plural object or a singular object plus a prepositional phrase with _from_. A subordinate clause object doesn't work, which is why the last example in the question sounds wrong.

Comment: I am new here and don´t quite have the hang of things yet. Should I edit my answer to reflect Janus Bahs Jacquet´s clarification, or is it enough that the  correction comes in the form of a comment?

Comment: That's up to you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is [no restriction](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tell_apart) to refering to a person or negative mode.

So I would say **yes** to your questions.

For your student answer, as @JanusBahsJacquet said in comment,

> I’ve duck-taped my toothbrush, so we could tell which is whose

is enough and do not need *"apart"*.